# Conectar Subdominios a paginas creadas en Google Sites

Tags: subdominio

Tengo un dominio en Google Domains, tengo 2 paginas creadas en Google Sites, una para el dominio, la cual esta publicada y funcionando y la otra quiero conectarla a un subdominio de mi dominio. En la página de Google Domains te deja conectarla pero después de 48 horas no se ha publicado y sigue mandando el error de: 404. That’s an error. The requested URL / was not found on this server. That’s all we know.

Alguien sabe como se corrige?